# Best internationalization strategy for ZK

Tags: internationalization, zk

What strategies do you use to internationalize web application written in ZK?

I'm currently using their 'funny' syntax ${c:l('LABEL_NAME')}, but it is using mechanism which has 2 problems:

1) It is not accepting \uchcode syntax, which is standard for resource bundles in java. There's no way to edit such files from NetBeans.

2) They are using only one file for whole webapp, which can be extremally large and I'm afraid of possible performance factor.

Therefore I have 2 questions:

1) Is the using of single large properties file a performance problem?

2) Are there any other good methods to internationalize ZK app (zscript I don't consider good method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there doesn't have performance issue on load i18n message, it use fast hash to target a message, but a memory issue ( on load message text in to memory for different local). however i don't care memory issue since it is just text message and server is powerful and have huge memory.

and for me, I always use ascii as key, so no key-encoding issue.

one thing is not convenient is I can just set message in one i3 file, if I want to set multiple (for modularizing message) file I have to wright code registering a LabelLocator to Labels.

Answer (score 2):

1) it's not a issue for me. the language files are MUCH smaller than other files (so the loading of reading them are quite light)

2) imo, i won't use zscript in my online project, you can take a look the official performance tip - [Not to Use zscript for Better Performance](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Performance_Tips/Use_Compiled_Java_Codes#Not_to_Use_zscript_for_Better_Performance).

More info about internationalize ZK app, please refer to [ZK Developer's Reference - Labels](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Internationalization/Labels#Loading_Labels_from_Other_Resources)

btw, i used to create a LabelManager and manage the source in different langs/locales.

Comment: Well, usually language files are much smaller because there is typically separate language file for module/page. In ZK however, when there will be single file for whole application, this file may be the biggest ....

Answer (score 0):

As I know, c:l() is simply the default way to retrieve I18N labels. You could use the standard resource bundle if you like. All you have to do is to implement a static method and then use  to map it to a ZUL page.